# Kotlin: adding a mutable list into 2D mutable list duplicate it's previous lists to the newly added one

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 mutable lists

```
val line = mutableListOf<String>()
val minesField = mutableListOf<MutableList<String>>()
```

the aim of these 2 lists is to create a table of content made of X and 0 (9*9).

I have a function that creates the content of the `line` and at the end I add it to the `minesField`  mutablelist.
i tried to add it in several ways but all ended in the same result.

```
       minesField.add(line)
        minesField += line
        minesField.addAll(listOf(line))
```

what happens is that the last `line`  i add to `minesField` duplicates itself into all previously added lines/lists before. therefore at the end, i get a table of 9 duplicate lines to the last line i added.

i thought that this shouldn't happen since the function  `+= .add()` creates a new index for the newly added list/line only. it doesn't duplicate it all over the whole list...

how this can be solved?

Comment: Do you create a new mutable list for every line or just reuse the existing one (with `clear` for example)`?

Comment: everytime i enter the loop that creates the line, i clear the previous data from it and start over...

Comment: Could you please share the whole code that adds these lines? (with the loop)

Comment: @Joffrey well, it is not an issue because it was about copying the object into ```minesfiled``` not adding it as it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> i thought that this shouldn't happen since the function  += .add() creates a new index for the newly added list/line only.

That is correct. However, the new element points to the same `line` object as all the other elements, because you are using a single object for all lines. So this, for example:

```
minesField.add(line)
minesField.add(line)
```

causes `minesField` to be a list of two references to the same list (same as the list object that `line` refers to).

One way to make each line refer to a unique object and avoid duplication is to add a *copy* of `line` each time:

```
minesField.add(line.toMutableList())
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you perform `minesField.add(line)` repeatedly using exactly the same `line` object.

The point is: `minesField.add(line)` does not copy the contents of `line` into `minesField`. It adds the `line` object itself to it. If you then modify `line` you will modify the contents of `minesField` as well. As a result, you end up with `minesField` that contains 9 references to exactly the same `line` object.

You need to either create a new `line` object with each new line or you need to create a copy before adding to `minesField` by using: `line.toList()`.